# RPi cold boots into low resolution (LCD)

Tags: hdmi, debian, noobs

I have [this LCD](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-1-10-inch-TFT-LCD-Display-w-HDMI-VGA-Video-Driver-Board-for-Raspberry-Pi-/301581161486?) connected to my RPi B+ (HDMI). I have configured the boot config.txt to enable its 1024x600 resolution, however, on COLD boot - it runs at a lower resolution. Only after a SOFT reboot, does it come up in the proper full resolution.

Why would this be?